# How can I add custom attributes to all heading elements in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

**How to change the heading tags `<h1>` to `<h1 data-splitting>` and `<h2>` to `<h2 data-splitting>` and `<h3>` to `<h3 data-splitting>` and `<h4>` to `<h4 data-splitting>` in WordPress?**

How can I change them on all pages through hard coding or by change through JS/JQuery? (My pages are fully cached by Cloudflare CDN)

For hard coding, where should I look at, on theme files, or is it coded into the WordPress itself?

There are ID’s and classes such as `<div id="nav">` and `<div class="sidebar-box">` but what is the above type is called as? Is it same as `<h2>` + `<data-splitting>`?

This is required to add some animation effect to the headings - [View on Codepen](https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/YOPqLb)

Now how can I change heading tags?

I added this to the WordPress fuctions.php:-

```
 function enqueue_my_custom_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'hjs', 'https://example.com/h.js', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_custom_script' );
```

The h.js has the following code:-

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('h1, h2, h3, h4').attr('data-splitting', '');

});
```

But this doesn't add the script to the head.

I even added it manually as `<script async src="https://example.com/h.js">` but it does **not** gets show up in the head.

So I have added the JS file as an inline script in the head, now the script **does shows up in the head section as inline JS** but doesn't change the `<h1>` to `<h1 data-splitting>` and `<h2>` to `<h2 data-splitting>`.

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {

    $('h1, h2, h3, h4').attr('data-splitting', '');

});
</script
```

or as

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict()(function($) {
    $('document').ready(function() {

        $('h1, h2, h3, h4').attr('data-splitting', '');

    });
});
</script>
```

Now the script is present in the head as inline JS but it does not change the heading tags.

Comment: Couldn't you just change the trigger to a class? If you try to add this attribute via jQuery, it probably will happen too late for your effect to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tags that are coming from themes (mostly h1) require changes in template files.

For the tags which are coming from post contents, you can use the '[the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/)' filter to modify(find the list of heading tags using regex and modify it).